# Computer Goes to Sleep Within 2 Minutes Despite Settings

Tags: windows-10, sleep, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude 9410 with Windows 10 Professional. For some reason my computer goes to sleep within 1 to 2 minutes despite my power and sleep settings set to 30 to 45 minutes. I've tried a number of suggestions from forums and sources including the items listed below.

Any suggestions?

- Changed the plan settings for the both the “Balanced” and “Dell” plans under “Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options”. The “Dell” plan is the once selected, but I changed both.
- Changed the advanced power settings for the selected plan under “Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings”.
- Confirmed there is no a screensaver set under “Control Panel > Screensaver”.
- Completed all updates under Windows update.
- Confirmed the driver for the graphics card is up to date.
- Changed the “Attributes” registry setting under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0" from 1 to 2.
- Ran the troubleshooter for power options which reset my settings back to 2 to 4 minutes, rebooted, and then changed it back to my extended settings.

Comment: I put an answer here that said reset plans and update drivers (which had not been done). This was downvoted.  It would be useful to see a better answer.

Comment: That wasn't done by me. I was just coming to accept that as the answer. I used the "Dell Support Assist" application which found items (including drivers) that needed to be updated that were not found during the Windows update. Once I did that it began working properly. I also called Dell support who suggested removing their "Dell Optimizer" application which could have also caused problems (but it was working before doing that). Thank you!

Comment: I will undelete my my post if you are going to accept it. Thanks. It is now there for you to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through your list.

I cannot say about the registry change except to say I did not have to do this for Power Management to work correctly.

windows is up to date (you said).

Set both Balanced Plan and Dell Plan back to default settings.

Now get the Dell Driver Update App and update all drivers.

Be sure to update BIOS (UEFI) (normally a separate update) and then in the remaining driver updates make sure Power Driver and Firmwares are all updated.

Do a final restart and test.